# How can I perform database CRUD operations with text files with Python?

Tags: python

I've made an address book app using MySQL in PHP but now I want to make it in Python using a text file. Is it possible to perform CRUD operations with a text file instead of a database?

Comment: Yes it is. Is there a specific question you want to ask? This sort of general question isn't really good for this site. Please review the following: [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [the asking section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: actually i want to ask that , can we perform CRUD operations in File handling

Comment: I'm feeling a bit confused here: Do you want to use MySQL? If not, why include it in the question. OTOH, if you want to do this with just file operations, come up with a plan, try to develop it, and come back here when you encounter specific problems (like "Why can't I get a file to open?"). Also, please remember to search for similar questions before you ask a new one. I'm not meaning to be rude, but that is how this site works.

Comment: To address trying to do CRUD ops with just file operations: Having once maintained a database system that used a similar approach and was written entirely in FORTRAN, I'm sure it can be, but it might be a bigger task than you want to take on.

Comment: import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def writeFile():
    file = open('hello.txt','a+')
    file.write(metinF.get() + '\n')
    file.close()

gui = Tk()

metinF = Entry(gui)
metinF.grid(row=9, column=1)

butonWrite = Button(gui)
butonWrite.config(text = 'Write To File', command = writeFile)
butonWrite.grid(row=8, column=1)

gui.mainloop()      this is my code for writing data to file using gui. now i wan to display the data from the file on gui form

Comment: It is very difficult to read that code in that form. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54429492/edit) your question and add the code to it. Note that to properly format it you'll need to indent an extra 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the shelve module that's in the Python standard library. It basically gives you a dictionary that is easy to save to a file. However, you don't get a lot of relational database features like joining tables; it's just a key-value dictionary.

The documentation for it is at https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html

This doesn't really scale as well as using a database though.